# Is there a F#/.NET multiplatform lib like bpython-curTsies to make a nice repl?

Tags: f#, read-eval-print-loop, bpython

I need to make a custom REPL, and spoiled by bpython/ipython I wonder if exist something similar to it?

I wish to provide colored output, history, code completion, as close to http://ballingt.com/2014/05/13/bpython-curtsies-release.html as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [FSharp.Compiler.Services](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/).

I don't know bpython, but this sounds reasonably close.

Comment: Is not a REPL for F#, is for make one IN F# for a custom language/utility

Comment: @mamcx: edit your question then - there's not a word about a custom language in it and bpython is clearly a frontend to python interpreter.